# string manipulation with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I have been trying to manipulate a string ( like substring function in java)
so, most of the on-line guides point towards the following options :

```
   str.split("A").first
   str[0...15]
   str.from(0).to(15)
```

but whenever I use any of the above I get this error:

NoMethodError

```
1) undefined method 'split'

2) undefined method '[]'

3) undefined method 'from'
```

I guess there is some lib or something I am supposed to use. Any help towards the right direction would be appreciated.

Note : using ruby 2.0 and rails 4

Comment: its part of a result from a mysql database.

I get the date time as "2015-04-28T14:54:45.000Z". I guess its with time zones.

so basically, 
date = (result.created_date).split(T).first
or
date = result.created_date[0...15]

gives me a no method error

I want the result to be smthg like : "YYYY-MM-DD hh;mm:ss"

Comment: can you show full thing you do?

Comment: How are you assigning the `str` variable when you fetch the string from the db?

Comment: Make sure that `str` is a string. It will be good if you can show the value of `str`

Comment: My guess is that str isn't a string but a date object. When you print out a date object it will show a date-like string like that - but rails is smart enough to convert dates into actual DateTime objects (which aren't strings and have different methods)> So... what are you actually trying to do with this string? are you trying to extract out a particular part of the date? maybe you should try looking up the Date-method that does that and trying it on your "str" variable? (and maybe renaming the variable)

Comment: @smanvi To make sure that you've got a string you can do the following: `str.to_s`. Now you should be able to call `split` on it.

Comment: @newmediafreak .. trying that right now

Comment: @newmediafreak ... yes.. works 
thanks alot everyone

Comment: can you tell us your expected output?

Comment: @smanvi yes that works, but it's a brute-force approach. Can you tell us what you actually need from this date object because it is much better to just tell it to output in the format you actually want, rather than using string-manipulation.

Comment: I get the date time as "2015-04-28T14:54:45.000Z" from a mysql db 

I want the result to be smthg like : "YYYY-MM-DD hh;mm:ss"

Comment: @smanvi take a look on the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform string manipulation you need to have a `String` object, not something else:

```
str = 'this is string'
#=> "this is string"
str.split("i").first
#=> "th"
 str[0...5]
#=> "this "
```

There is no `from`/`to` methods on string, you use `[]` instead.

If you need to cast an object to string, there is [Object#`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-to_s) method.

## EDIT

To convert a valid date string into `DateTime` object use [`to_datetime`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime):

```
"2015-04-28T14:54:45.000Z".to_datetime
#=> Tue, 28 Apr 2015 14:54:45 +0000
```

To play with its presentation, use [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime):

```
"2015-04-28T14:54:45.000Z".to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#=> "2015-04-28 14:54:45"
```